# Facebook JS SDK login button doesn't show log out when logged in?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using the code from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button

I am using the following HTML:

```
<div onlogin="loggedIn" class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium"></div>
```

The button appears on the site OK.

The app is not in sandbox mode, the URLs are all correct (and not localhost)

When I click the "Log in" button the dialog appears asking me to authenticate with FB. Once authenticated the dialog disappears and `loggedIn` is called... But the button still says "Log in"?

Do I need to swap this manually? If so how? Should it happen automatically?

I have tried with: `data-auto-logout-link="true"`  but that doesn't change anything...

Comment: *I have tried with: data-auto-logout-link="true" but that doesn't change anything* - this can't happen, can you please re-check and show some more relevant code

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```

Use this code instead...